# Quick time event script

Tags: autohotkey, autoit, ahk2

I wanted to learn how to make a quick time event script so when letters at the bottom of my screen appear the script will press them keys is there any websites or people that could help me make this script?

My friend tried making one for me but the script kept repeating random letters and we gave up

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.